# How can I get a JSON file so that I can alter/do stuff with it in my native JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm currently trying to learn how to do data holding and properties and stuff, and I suppose that includes learning JSON. But in order to actually do the JSON, I need a file.

**Question**: How can I reference a JSON file so that I can extract values from it and do data... things?

Note: I ONLY need help referencing the JSON file for now, I don't need help learning JSON yet.

Note: I am using native languages, I am NOT using jQuery (I know people haven't used it in the better part of a decade, but I have seen solutions to this question using jQuery). All other posts I have seen solve the problem using frameworks, but nothing in native JS and HTML.

Note: I know that "data holding" is vague, but I don't know the terms and language to explain things yet. You will see what I mean in my JavaScript.

Note: I'm also doing this on the browser version of vsCode if that makes a difference.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Data stuff and JSON</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please don't mind the messiness, this JavaScript is just notes for me.

JavaScript:

```
function logMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg + ". ";
}

//This creates one person with the attributes/properties displayed below.
//These attributes/properties can be got by objectName.propertyName or with objectName["propertyName"]
const Person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "Unknown",
    occupation: "Unknown",
    fullName: function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}

//This returns the first and last name we are using here
let personFullName = Person.fullName();

//logMessage(personFullName);
//logMessage(Person.occupation + ", " + Person.age);

//Creates a class that multiple things can be made from.
//Kind of like what is above.
class Car {
    constructor({position, velocity, weight, acceleration, make, model, color, length, width, height}) {
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.acceleration = acceleration;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

//car is a Car with specific elements
const car = new Car ({
    position: {
        x: 176,
        y: 41
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    weight: 3570,
    acceleration: 10,
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Avalon",
    color: "White",
    length: 195.9,
    width: 72.8,
    height: 56.5
})

//logMessage(car.position.x);
//logMessage(car.weight);
//logMessage(car.model)

//This is a text version of JSON. This is one way to do it.
let text = '{ "employees" : [' +
'{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}'

//This turns all of the text above into an array, I think
let object = JSON.parse(text);
let randomName = object.employees[0].firstName + " " + object.employees[2].lastName;
```

JSON (`objects.json`):

```
{
    "Team Members" : [
        {
            "firstName":"John",
            "lastName":"Doe",
            "employeeCode":"2219"
        }, 
        {
            "firstName":"Jane",
            "lastName":"Smith",
            "employeeCode":"6340"
        }
    ]
}
```

I suppose that I was expecting to be able to do the JSON inside the JS file, but then I learned that it is it's own thing.

Comment: There are possibly some fundamental misconceptions here: 1. you can't reference a file on the server directly in client-side Javascript 2. "all of these files are local" not as far as the browser is concerned. They could be halfway across the internet or sitting on the same dev laptop, doesn't matter 3. nobody who had any choice in the matter has used jQuery in the last better part of a decade, you don't have to tell us you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the JSON file using `Fetch API`:

```js
async function fetchJSON() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('./objects.json');
    const data = await response.json();

    // DO STUFF TO YOUR JSON HERE

  } catch (error) {
    // ...
  }
}
```